# Riddle about moving ahead

Tags: riddle

I'm a word that's simple, but I carry great power,
I signify progress, a direction to empower.

Don't look back, best foot first just in case.
I even describe how the clocks can race.

I'm a word that's a symbol of moving ever ahead,
Even if it makes it a struggle to get out of bed.

I'm a word that's crucial, for progress and growth,
From the start to the finish, I help you stay on both.

What am I?

Comment: Did you come up with this riddle?

Comment: @bobble no, I just found it and I cannot figure it out! Unfortunately I don't know the correct answer, best I came up with was daylight/step/turn but I'm not sure they fit in exactly.

Comment: In that case, please [edit] your question to add [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7259) - it's a site requirement so that we give proper credit to puzzle creators. No worry @Marky since you're new, it's very simple - for example, if you got this off a website, all you have to do is give us a link.

Comment: (No need to delete/deface the post if you can't find the original author - as bobble suggests, even just a link to the site where you find it will do. Thanks!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the word is -

> **Forward**

I'm a word that's simple, but I carry great power, I signify progress, a direction to empower.

> Yes, it is a simple word. But moving forward does signify progress. A little wordplay with "direction" reference.

Don't look back, best foot first just in case. I even describe how the clocks can race.

> "Look forward" is quite a common phrase so again a bit wordplay there on "dont look back". The reference to clocks is a metaphor for how quickly time moves forward.

I'm a word that's a symbol of moving ever ahead, Even if it makes it a struggle to get out of bed.

> Forward - Ahead. Reference of getting out of bed is as @tmpearce rightly pointed out in comments, it refers to [Spring Forward](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time#Mnemonic) i.e. Daylight savings when you need to get up early because of time change.

I'm a word that's crucial, for progress and growth, From the start to the finish, I help you stay on both.

> Its a cruicial word ofcourse. Keeping a forward mindset leaving the past behind helps us both in progress and growth. Professional and personal both.

Comment: I think "Even if it makes it a struggle to get out of bed" likely refers to rot13(Gur "fcevat sbejneq" punatr bs pybpx sbe qnlyvtug fnivat gvzr, juvpu rssrpgviryl trgf evq bs na ubhe bs fyrrc ol znxvat rirelbar jnxr hc na ubhe rneyvre guna orsber gur gvzr punatr.)

Comment: @tmpearce Ah, makes perfect sense. I didnt knew its also called with that name. Thanks :)

Comment: One more for you: "best foot first" is a strange phrase. "Chg lbhe orfg sbbg *sbejneq* vf n pbzzba Ratyvfu vqvbz.